# Angular-Slim: CORS when call post

Tags: php, angular

From localhost: 4200 I am trying to make a POST request, to my Slim REST API (3.0 v), which I have hosted on a server.
when I execute the "post" query, the following error appears:
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3dFA.png)

**This is my code in the api:**

```html
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \Slim\App;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

$app = new Slim\App(['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' => true]]);

//permite el acceso cors.
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});

$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization,token')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS')
        ->withHeader('access-control-expose-headers', 'token,Authorization');
});

require_once "src/routes/routes.php";

$app->run();
```

**ANGULAR: : auth.service.ts**

```html
import { GLOBAL } from './global';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  observe: 'response' as 'response',
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  public url: string;

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router) {   this.url = GLOBAL.url; }

  login(user) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'login', user, httpOptions);
  };

  loggedIn() {
    //devuelve true si contiene token o falso
    return !!localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
  registrarse(user) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'usuario', user, httpOptions)
  };
}
```

**ANGULAR: : home.component.ts**

```html
import { Empresa } from './../../models/empresa';
import { EmpresaService } from './../../services/empresa.service';
import { AuthService } from './../../services/auth.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  empresa: Empresa;
  user = {
    'id': '',
    'email': ''
  }

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private empresaService: EmpresaService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEmpresa();
    this.postLogin();
  }

  // This request goes well.
  getEmpresa() {
    let id = 1;
    this.empresaService.getEmpresa(id).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log(result)
        this.empresa = result['data'];
      }
    )
  }

  // This request shows me the error
  postLogin() {    
    let user = {
      'email': 'adri',
      'password': 'adri'
    }
    this.authService.login(user).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log(result.body)
        this.user = result.body['data'];
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Note*:
when I put the API in localhost, the two requests work very well for me: The getEmpresa () and the postLogin ().
but when I put the api on the server, the postLogin () fails.

Answer (score 0):

Angular by default sends in body requests in Content-Type: application / json.

And it is seen that in a more optimized way in production it must be sent in Content-Type: in text / plain.

I have added this code in angular:

```html
const httpOptions = {
  observe: 'response' as 'response',
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type':  'text/plain',
   })

};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  public url: string;

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router) {   this.url = GLOBAL.url; }


  login(user) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'login', user, httpOptions)
  }
```

and in my REST Slim API I have added the following:
-> json_decode: to decrypt the file that is in JSON format

```html
$app->post('/login', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $db = conexion();
    $json = $request->getBody();
    $input = json_decode($json, true);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email= :email";
    ...
    ...
    }
```